# How to set a release tag to a milestone in GitLab 12.5.2

Tags: git, gitlab

Heyho,

since today Im using GitLab 12.5.2 and trying to connect a milestone with a release tag. But it doesnt work despite the instructions of the GitLab docs.

**Does anyone know how to connect a milestone with a (new) release tag?**

I tried it with the following instructions:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/milestones/
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#releases-associated-with-milestones

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is you cant do it via the GitLab UI. You need to take the API. Probably because the common workflow for releases is via CI/CD.

Here is an example request

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: gDybLx3yrUK_HLp3qPjS" \
     --data '{ "name": "New release", "tag_name": "v0.3", "description": "Super nice release", "milestones": ["v1.0", "v1.0-rc"], "assets": { "links": [{ "name": "hoge", "url": "https://google.com" }] } }' \
     --request POST https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/releases
```

Documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/index.html#create-a-release